# cvs segfaults when using pserver

Tags: segmentation-fault, cvs

I'm trying to setup a CVS server, but when I login (using pserver), I get a segfault, and the login fails.

I can access the local repository quite fine, and I have setup a single user in `CVSROOT/passwd`. Running `cvs -d CVSROOT login` works fine - I get prompted for the password, and I can checkout the files.

But when I test the pserver protocol (because I want to connect from a remote machine) using the command `cvs -d :pserver:cvsuser@localhost:CVSROOT login` I get an error message from the client: "end of file from server".

I then check in `/var/log/messages`, and I find these lines:

```
Jun 15 22:55:23 granbo-1 xinetd[437]: START: cvspserver pid=17064 from=::1
Jun 15 22:55:23 granbo-1 kernel: [ 1712.522236] cvs[17064]: segfault at 0 ip b755d508 sp bfd80f0c error 4 in libc-2.16.so[b740f000+1b0000]
Jun 15 22:55:23 granbo-1 xinetd[437]: EXIT: cvspserver signal=11 pid=17064 duration=0(sec)
```

The version of cvs is: cvs-1.11.23-29.fc18.i686

Do you have any idea what is the problem? Clearly, this is a very simple setup and should work for everyone.

Can you suggest anything I can do to help debug the problem? I'm familiar with gdb, but I don't know how to start gdb, when cvs is started from xinetd.

Can you suggest another way to access the repository from a remote machine? I'm using ssh to connect to the machine.

Comment: I've managed to run valgrind on the cvs process (by disabling xinetd and starting cvs using netcat. The complete command I used was:

    valgrind -v --trace-children=yes --log-file=val.%p nc --exec "/usr/bin/cvs -f --allow-root=/share/CVS-Root pserver" -l 2401

Comment: This gave me a stack trace:

    ==17544== Invalid read of size 1
    ==17544==    at 0x402B48A: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:730)
    ==17544==    by 0x809464B: check_password (server.c:5651)
    ==17544==    by 0x809A5F2: pserver_authenticate_connection (server.c:6076)
    ==17544==    by 0x804C104: main (main.c:730)
    ==17544==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: Can  you try out 1.12.13?